# How can I install-package via PM console to all projects that already references this package?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, nuget

Is there a short-cut in PM console so that I can do something like in my solution:

```
install-package enttityframework -toAllProjectsThatReferencesEntityFramework
```

**In another words** to instruct NuGet to install a package where it is already used in my solution by multiple projects to that it updates all those projects by installing the latest version of the package?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Update-Package](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference#Update-Package). This will update the package for all projects that have it installed.

```
Update-Package EntityFramework
```

Comment: It complains that it cannot find the package. Which is not the case when I call: install-package EntityFramework